# Helper function and iteration

Tags: canjs, canjs-view

My input data is a comma-enumerated list, e.g. "en,fr,es" for a set of languages I speak.
I want my template to render it as a list using ul/li.

I have defined a helper function that can transform the "en,fr,es" into an array ["en", "fr", "es"] using the Javascript split.

```
can.stache.registerHelper('split_comma', function(str, options) {
    return str.split(",");
});
```

But I cannot figure out how to make the template work?

Assuming the following context:
    { Language: "en,fr,es",
      languages: ["en", "fr", "es"] }

```
{{#each languages}} {{this}} and {{/each}}
```

returns the right stuff.

```
{{#each split_comma Language}} {{this}} and {{/each}}
```

does not return anything.

It seems that the helper function does not take precedence.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not how Handlebars helpers work. What you probably want to do is to introduce a new section with the `split_comma` helper that has the language array as the context:

```
can.stache.registerHelper('split_comma', function(str, options) {
    return options.fn(str.split(","));
});
```

and then iterate over that:

```
{{#split_comma Language}}
    {{#each .}} {{this}} and {{/each}}
{{/split_comma}}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Another option was to have a helper function modify the object before the template is applied. But this is  not very transparent. Thanks.